# Blocks on Blocks and weak pointers

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have two almost identical methods, both of which are AFNetworking 2.0 calls, using blocks as callbacks. Each gets posts from one endpoint, and then in the completion block, gets other posts from another endpoint, and in that second completion block I sort and merge to two lists.

While inside of both sets of completion blocks, I use `weakSelf`, a weak pointer to the current view controller (`__weak instancetype weakSelf = self;`). This works fine in my getNewPosts method, but not my getMorePosts method. They only differ in the GET parameters and where they're inserted into the main feed of sorted content (newPosts uses `[weakSelf.datasource insertObject:atIndex:i]` and morePosts uses `[weakSelf.datasource addObject:]`)

However it seems the problem stems from when I call `[weakSelf mergeLists::]`. I use the exact same method in the exact same way (in double blocked callbacks) but in fetchNewPosts I get null returned to me, which is impossible with the method's implementation. Oddly, I only get null when I call the method from weakSelf. fetchNewPosts can call `[weakSelf mergeLists::]` no problem.

Does anyone have any idea why I can or can't use a weak pointer to self when self isn't changing?

Comment: Any reason why you can't show the code you're talking about?

Comment: It's just really messy and proper-nouny. Give me a minute to edit the above.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I'm an idiot, I wasn't setting the weakSelf.
 `__weak instancetype *weakSelf = self;` vs `__weak instancetype *weakSelf;`

I would expect calling methods and properties on a nil object would raise some sort of warning instead of just spitting out nils all the time.

Comment: "I would expect calling methods and properties on a nil object would raise some sort of warning" Welcome to Objective-C. Yes, this is why I asked to see to the code. I was pretty sure you were just sending a message to nil.